# Obtaining data using model relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an application for the first time using Laravel. I need to fill a form using model-form binding which requires passing the data to the form.

Now the data which I need to pass is in a table called "teachers". It has corresponding Model and Controller both. The users table is the standard Laravel table. The users and teachers are related via "email". I tested the relashionships on Tinker which shows desired output as follows.

> >>> **$user = App\User::find(15);**
>   => App\User {#2947
>        id: 15,
>        name: "First",
>        email: "first@example.com",
>        email_verified_at: null,
>        created_at: "2019-04-19 17:10:59",
>        updated_at: "2019-04-19 17:10:59",    }
>   >>> **$user->teacher**
>   => App\teacher {#2948
>        sdrn: 856,
>        name: "First",
>        surname: null,
>        deptname: null,
>        deptcode: null,
>        designation: null,
>        email: "first@example.com",
>        mobile: null,
>        cc: "N",
>        created_at: "2019-04-19 17:10:59",
>        updated_at: "2019-04-19 17:10:59",    }

Thus, the relationships are working alirght since the tinker commands are bringing correct row from teachers table.

However when I get the logged in teacher via Auth library as

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $teacher = $user->teacher();
 dd();
```

the output of dd() shows something like

> BelongsTo {#270 ▼ 
>    #child: User {#273 ▶}
>    #foreignKey:
>   "email"
>    #ownerKey: "email"
>    #relationName: "teacher"
>   #query: Builder {#267 ▶}
>    #parent: User {#273 ▶}
>    #related: teacher {#262 ▶}
>    #withDefault: null
>  }

This is not what I need. I need to pass the corresponding row from teachers table to the form. Tinker gives the desired result alright but the `Auth:user()` is returning some funny object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either:

```
$user->teacher()->first()
```

to fetch the first (and only) result of the relationship, or a "magic" shortcut for that:

```
$user->teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
$user = Auth::user();
$teacher = $user->teacher;  //this will load related article models as a collection
dd($teacher);
```